# Serve frontend from /frontend rather than /

Tags: svelte, vite

Essentially when I do on a brand new vite/svelte project (not sveltekit)

```
pnpm run
```

It runs on localhost:3000/

However, I am attempting to run it on

```
http://localhost:3000/frontend
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base), in your vite config:

> **Default**: /
>
> Base public path when served in development or production.